# Which takes precedence VIA or Contact header?

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio

As the title says which should take precedence when replying back to a UAS. I have a provider that sends a VIA header that is different to the contact header. They are stating that I should be sending SIP signalling back to the URI in the contact header. But Kamailio is sending it back to URI in the VIA header.

I can not find an RFC which shows the precedence.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via and Contact Header serves different purpose:

Via Header: It indicates the list of all the network node (server,proxy-server etc.) the request traversed from originating point to the endpoint.

**Via Header is used by the User Agent Server (UAS) to return/reply the SIP status responses (e.g. SIP 100 Trying, 180 Ringing, etc.)**

Contact Header: Contact header basically contains the SIP URI of the end user, that the **originating user can use to send future requests to.** That is, requests that belong to the same dialog, such as re-INVITE, BYE and ACK messages. (The Contact header field has a role similar to the Location header field in HTTP.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no precedence, they serve different purposes.

The response should be sent to the URI in the [VIA header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-20.42).

You can use the Contact header URI to compute the Request URI for new requests within this session.

Comment: So, I should only be using the contact header if they do a target refresh such as a re-INVITE?

Comment: Yes, it can be used to contact the sender of the INVITE for subsequent requests